# Multiple panic in single test without code duplicaton

Tags: rust

I want to test for multiple panics but that causes code duplication

eg.

```
#[test]
fn test_without_panic() {
    CODEBLOCK1
}

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "It will panic1")]
fn test_with_panic1() {
    CODEBLOCK1
    CODEBLOCK2

}

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "It will panic2")] 
fn test_with_panic2() {
    CODEBLOCK1
    CODEBLOCK3
}
```

What is best way for testing panic without repeating the code.

Comment: Ya, changed the question. @trentcl

Comment: I am thinking to write a function for CODEBLOCK1, is that the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, write a helper function, and pass values out of it if you need to.

```
fn setup() -> (Things, Tests, Need) {
    CODEBLOCK1
    (stuff, from, codeblock1)
}

#[test]
fn test_setup_succeeds() {
    setup();
}

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "It will panic1")]
fn test_with_panic1() {
    let (a, b, c) = setup();
    CODEBLOCK2

}

#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "It will panic2")] 
fn test_with_panic2() {
    let (a, b, c) = setup();
    CODEBLOCK3
}
```

The advantage of this over arranging to write all of the above in one test function (which you *could* do with [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html), I imagine) is that each test can succeed or fail independently, which means that if your tests do fail, you get more information about the problem than if the first panic or lack of panic stopped the test.